# The required attribute "Include" is missing from element <ProfileInclude>

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm doing an internship in France and I'm developping a Delphi multi-platform application using FireMonkey in RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo. My internship tutor installed a Mac mini to test my application on Mac OSX.

Every time I build on this platform (OSX32), it works the first time, and then I got this error

> message: "C:\Users\rgibassier\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\DEV\19.0\MacOSX10.12.4.sdk".

I can fix it temporarily by erasing the file and replacing it with an older copy that I kept, which has not been corrupted yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the existing SDK (Tool->Options->SDK Manager) resolved for me